# Postgresql: exclude records where a specific character in text is not prefaced by whitespace

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to exclude records that have a `">"` with no whitespace directly infront of the `>` character.

So return records like:

`" >"`

`"I worked on deals >50MM"`

But **not** like:

`">"`

`"I like accoun>ng"`

While parsing and saving PDFs, some characters we're incorrectly converted into `>` and I'd like to skip these records, but not records where `>` was legimately used. Legitimate cases generally have a whitespace, `" "` infront of the `">"`.

**Current (but problematic) solution:**

```
select 
    id, content
from uploads 
where (
    content ilike '%>%' and
    content ilike '% >%'
) or (
    content not ilike '%>%'
)
```

The problem with this solution is that it will select records that have both ">" and " >". But I'd like to exclude everything missing a whitespace in front of ">".

Hopefully this question is not too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular expressions:

```
where not content ~ ' >'
```

or perhaps:

```
where content ~ '[^ ]>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
select id,content from uploads
  where id not in (select id from uploads where content like '%>%'
                   except
                   select id from uploads where content like '% >%')
```